How can I execute .pyz files in another Python script
So you know how you can simply execute another python script in memory using:
with open('my_script.py', 'r') as my_script:
    exec(my_script.read())

How can I do the same with .pyz files without writing/unzipping data onto the disk?
I tried:
with open('my_script.pyz', 'rb') as my_script:
    exec(my_script.read())

However I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onyz/Cop/l.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec(my_script.read())
SyntaxError: source code string cannot contain null bytes


You need to unzip it first so that the Python interpreter can evaluate the statements.
